# undefined method `steps' for #<Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow:xxx> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara, site-prism

My cucumber feature file is using scenario outline like below:

```
Scenario Outline: 
  And user searches for item "<item>"
  Then homepage is active
  And user selects "<type>" Type(s)

Examples:
  | item | type |
  | car | bmw   |
  | car | honda  |
```

Throws this below error message on :

```
undefined method `steps' for #<Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow:0x007f83buyg71120> 
(NoMethodError)
```

I am using cucumber 1.3.19 and in my env.rb file before hook, i am using below where the error is thrown from:

```
scenario.steps.map(&:name)
```

Comment: Could you post all of the code from your before hook in your env.rb?  You likely want to call `scenario.test_steps.map(&:name)`; but `scenario` in the case that I tested was `Cucumber::RunningTestCase::ScenarioOutlineExample` (using the `Before do |scenario|` [scenario hook](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#scenario-hooks)), not `Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow` from your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by upgrading my cucumber version to 2.0.2